# Using a subclassed UILabel in a UIView category with Associated References

Tags: ios, objective-c, subclass, objective-c-category

I'm trying to use the MTAnimatedLabel class (https://github.com/mturner1721/MTAnimatedLabel) inside of a UIView Category (scalessec's iOS Toast from here: https://github.com/scalessec/Toast)

I understand I probably need to use Obj-C associated references. Here's how I'm trying to do it:

```
    MTAnimatedLabel *existingTestLabel = (MTAnimatedLabel *)objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &testLabelKey);
if(existingTestLabel != nil) return;

MTAnimatedLabel *testLabel = [[[MTAnimatedLabel alloc] initWithFrame:testFrame] autorelease];
testLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Test String."];
NSLog(@"testLabel: %@", testLabel.text);
objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &testLabelKey, testLabel, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
[self addSubview:testLabel];
[testLabel startAnimation];
```

It fails with an EXC_BAD_ACCESS on this line:

```
    MTAnimatedLabel *testLabel = [[[MTAnimatedLabel alloc] initWithFrame:testFrame] autorelease];
```

My testLabelKey is defined as:

```
static char const * const testLabelKey = "testLabel";
```

and my testLabel propety is declared in the interface as:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) MTAnimatedLabel *testLabel;
```

Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong, or suggest a different way? Thanks!

Comment: One where is your testFrame initialized? Two, why are you using objc_getAssociatedObject/objc_setAssociatedObject ?

Comment: testFrame is declared just above the code I copied and pasted:

    CGRect testFrame = CGRectMake(110, 100, 300, 40);

I'm using get/setAssociatedObject per the suggestion here:

http://ddeville.me/2011/03/add-variables-to-an-existing-class-in-objective-c/

Comment: I'm also following the example for associated references here:

http://oleb.net/blog/2011/05/faking-ivars-in-objc-categories-with-associative-references/

Comment: And you are 100% sure that that's the line which is causing the crash ? Because I checked MTAnimatedLabel for any hidden problems, but the code should work.

Comment: Yes, 100%. I set a breakpoint and it crashes when I step over that line.

Comment: Just another suggestion, remove the `autorelease` form the alloc/init and release it  after your `[self addSubview:testLabel];`

Comment: Moving the release doesn't help, thanks anyway danypata